# Constructor dependency injection with ViewModels

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I'm exploring MVVM and was wondering if it's possible to inject dependencies into ViewModels without using a DI library (e.g. Dagger)?

I'll have multiple ViewModels and multiple dependencies, some shared - but they should only be constructed once.

Comment: if you don't want to use a DI framework, you will have to instantiate the VMs manually

Comment: @Blackbelt In a ViewModelFactory right? So I guess my question becomes how would I get the dependencies into the factory? Would it be a case of creating the dependencies wherever that's done -> creating the factories (with the dependencies passed in) -> pass the factories to where relevant ViewModel is obtained with ViewModelProvider?